# Stop or kill a service

Tags: android, service, kill

I am developing a task manager application..

In that app, I display to the user a list of running apps and kill button beside each app.
When user presses kill button the corresponding activity will be killed and i used

```
      activitymanager.killbackgroundprocesses(packageName)
```

I created another application called service notification where user can start and stop a service by clicking on button "start service" and button "stop service" respectively..     Then before running my task manager app, i started the service from service notification app.
So this activity was displayed in my task manager app.

But when i kill that activity, it disappears from the list and then appears again because the service is restarting..How do I kill the sevice then?

I used startService and onCreate for starting service and showing some notification and stopService and onDestroy for stopping service...

Comment: ~"before running my task manager app, i started the service from service notification app".  So what you're saying is that you start all services regardless of whether the user chose to start them or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question...

After using

```
activitymanager.killbackgroundprocesses(packageName) ,
```

we have to check if there are any services running under that package name or process name.

Then we have to use

```
stopService(new Intent().setComponent(serviceInfos.get(i).service))
```

But it would return an error because android does not allow us to stop another service

So I used these two lines in the manifest and then ran my app in the build machine

```
coreApp="true" 
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

These two lines are there in the android settings manifest file, which allows settings to stop service if the user wants.

So the activity got killed along with the service... :)

And remember this worked only on the build machine....

Comment: what is build machine，you mean it is the mobile you doing it?

Comment: coreApp="true" means that it is a system app that gets distributed by an OEM or Google itself?

Answer (score 2):

Try To Use this permission in your android Manifest File.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

and Look at this link it may be helpfull...
      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29

and this: 
[Start a service on onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411499/start-a-service-on-onclick)

Comment: ya I have used that permission and I am able to kill other activities too..except the activity with this service